# R: Error in fBody[[i]] : no such index at level 4

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling

Debug mode in R sometimes throws out the following error:

```
     Error in fBody[[i]] : no such index at level 4
```

What causes this? And how to avoid it?

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to give a proper advice. What kind of debugger are you using? RStudio debugging mode perhaps? Are you calling browser(), debugonce(), are recovering the trace after a crash or some other method? A reproducible example would go a long way.

Comment: I am using RStudio debugSource(). Unfortunately it would be difficult for me to build an example right now, I will try to make one later though.

Comment: You don't need an example. This is a very common problem in RStudio.

Answer (score 54):

This is a bug in RStudio. I frequently get it while writing my R code. This is all I always do and work:

1. Restarted RStudio
2. Clear all breakpoints (there is a menu for that)
3. Cut the entire source code, the file you want to debug. Save the empty file.
4. Paste the source code. Save it.

The bug has something to do with position of the breakpoints. For some reason, RStudio is confused the new breakpoints with something else. By cutting and pasting the source code, we are forcing RStudio to "forget" the old breakpoints and start refresh. It's like giving a new file to RStudio.

Now, you can run a debug session again.

RStudio developers, **please** fix this stupid bug.

Comment: Note that it is over a year since the question was asked and the bug is still present.

Comment: Bug still present in RStudio 1.0.136. This solution still works thankfully.

Comment: in the new version, it looks like simply clearing breakpoints and re-sourcing is sufficient

Comment: Does not do the trick for me running RStudio 1.2.1335. I cannot believe this bug made it this far. It is unbelievably annoying.

Comment: not that its been 6 years and the bug still present

Comment: reaching 8 years :-(

Answer (score 19):

On mac, I usually use:

1. Save file
2. Debug->Clear All Breakpoints.

It helps even without restarting RStudio

Comment: Step-2 and step-1, respectively, works for me on macOS.

Answer (score 6):

1. Save file without breakpoints
2. Session -> Restart R

Usually works for me...

Comment: Works like a charm in Windows!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if every individual element and make sure it is a length of 1. In my case I had `c <- (1:23)` 
`fit[[c]]$results["Accuracy"]` some of it was length 1 but at index 3 it was length > 1

fit[[3]] I had the following ...

Accuracy

1 0.7764711

2 0.7771532

so I used `max(fit[[3]]$results["Accuracy"])` for the ones that had length greater than one and then the mean function.